# Cross file Define

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to implement a system for safer updating and testing of updates to my website. The idea is to have two virtual hosts, one pointing to the production version, and another for the development version. Then when the updates are approved the I could reconfigure the virtual host to switch with site is the production and which is the development. When not actively working on the development that host is disabled using `a2dissite`

I want to reduce the changes required to transfer the site to as few lines as possible to reduce the possibility of making an error when doing so. I came up with this solution that should only involve making a single line change:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

        Define current_site lambda

        ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/site_${current_site}/

        [...]

        # Set environment variables for PHP code.
        SetEnv ENVIROMENT production
        SetEnv CURRENT_SITE ${current_site}

        [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

With the development site file looking like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName beta.mydomain.com

        <If "%{current_site} == 'lambda'">
                Define beta_site gamma
        </If>
        <Else>
                Define beta_site lambda
        </Else>

        ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com/site_${beta_site}/


        [...]

        # Set environment variables for PHP code.
        SetEnv ENVIROMENT development
        SetEnv CURRENT_SITE ${beta_site}

        [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

When checking this with `apachectl configtest` I get an error in my development file stating, `Cannot parse condition clause: Variable 'current_site' does not exist`. The [apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#define) says

> The variable is always globally defined and not limited to the scope
> of the surrounding config section.

This leads me to believe as long as my production file is processed first the variable should be defined. At first I thought this may be an processing order error, so I checked the documentation and found that the [include](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) directive in apache's default configuration that brings in the enabled sites uses alphabetical order. I made my production site's conf file start with 000 so that it would be processed first but I still have the error. What am I misunderstanding or doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `apache2ctl -S`? This will display the virtualhosts in order, as apache is processing them.

Comment: @Diamond I would prefer not to post the whole output since it contains some domain info, but it does confirm that the virtualhosts are being processed in the order I intended. It also shows the define list at the end that includes my current_site. All this only if the if statement is removed so the config is valid, it just repeats the error otherwise.